# Can I have static property per session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've got partial class as code-behind for my form where I have

```
private object x;
```

And I'm trying to use it on Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (x != null)
        y = x;
```

first time it's null but then by clicking an element in `TreeView` I set it to some object and it's not null there. It shows on form.

When I'm trying to work with object in web form, form is processing `Page_Load` again and `x` is null there. How can I keep `x` static for each open session?

Comment: `volotile`? My guess is you either using it for no reason OR you have code that is probably work wrong on server...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, I used it for no reason, was trying to understand why the page processing re-initialization, removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, static won't remain for the session between requests. You'd probably want to make use of the Session dictionary here. It's something that comes in on all code-behind page files.

```
Session["x"] = 10;
// if you want you can do:
// var x = Session["x"];
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["x"]))
{
    y = Session["x"];
}
```

The code above doesn't take into account casting x. So if y is an int, you could do this in the if block:

```
// imagine there's some type safety checks somewhere, yada yada
y = Convert.ToInt32(Session["x"]);
```

This keeps variables for the lifetime of the session. To prove a point, try doing this in 2 different browsers at the same time. They'll both keep different values for x.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Heather Realised I forgot a few helpful bits, hope it's better now :)

Comment: Side note: while suggestion to use `Session` is good, statement "static won't remain for the session between requests" is somewhat wrong - it will definitely stick "forever" in same AppDomain - making it shared between all requests (as you pointing out `Session` is correct place for "per-user-session" data storage between requests).